# jQueryUI effects: multiple click issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a box which needs to bounce and highlight at the same time.

I use this code for effect and works perfectly:

```
$(".box").click(function () {
    $("#id1").effect("highlight", {color:"#669966"}, 2000).effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300).dequeue().unbind(click);
});
```

But if you click second time before the animation finish, the box doesn't come to it's original color.

Here is jFiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/EyeD4/

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `unbind(click)` to `unbind('click')`.

You were trying to unbind a variable called `click`, which was ineffective.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/EyeD4/1/

Unrelated, but I suggest using `.on('click')` and `.off('click')` instead of `.click` and `.unbind('click')`, respectively.

Comment: thank you! but it makes item unclickable completely, i need box to be clickable after effect finished, can you help with this also.

Comment: Just bind the event again after the effect has finished: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/EyeD4/4/